# How to Restore Deleted Post Not in Trash

Tags: customization

I accidentally deleted a post and don't see it in Trash.  How can I recover and restore it.  Just did it an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

If your post isn't in Trash, then it was completely deleted. The only way to restore it is recovering your database from an earlier backup. If you don't have backups and your post was deleted from the database - there is no way to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the posts, you can't no longer access it. If you would like to verify your deleted post are available or not, you could check in your wordpress database table named -> **prefix_posts** (table) and check **post_status** column. If you found your post is still in trash in that column. Make that **trash** to **publish**.

Comment: Hi, Por.  How do I get to my Wordpress database table named prefix_posts?

Comment: Hi @brajesh , Go though phpmyadmin from your hosting. prefix_posts means when you install wordpress, you gave a name to all of wordpress database table. Please check my screenshot https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/1RizMdlQH.png

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting account may have a daily backup of database. So please

1. Login to your account
2. Select Backup Restore
3. Select the date to recover from (in your case previous day)
4. Restore database.
   and you would see your deleted page back in your dashboard.

P.S : Responding to this post though old one, so that it helps someone looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

If your post isn't in the thrash section then it would have been deleted permanently. The only way to restore it is by rolling out to the previous back up . Else I am afraid you have to redo the task again.